# Creating files in gitlab via api fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have admin token with all privileges but when I am trying to create files via api I am getting this message: `You are not allowed to push into this branch`. I checked and this repository master branch is not protected, I wonder what could be the case?

Comment: Please provide the API call you are doing

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `Sudo` header, which is required when action is done on behalf of user.